# Weird Base64 Encoding

Tags: java, base64

I have found weird thing about base64 decoding

As far as I know, asterisk(*) is not a base64 charater.

Accdently,  I tested base64 decoding with string that includ asterisk

Here the code

```
String test = "icUI6W/ViQ4HNnA62XDbnBknC4CO4hpizE726rPT2Z+Z+/VHteyx1txPpb4ytqngfezfVo/*bTVr";
sun.misc.BASE64Decoder bd = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
data = bd.decodeBuffer(test);
```

I expect some exceptions occure, But not that

Can Any one explain that?

Is it sun java bug?

Thanks

Comment: Which Base64 class are you using? That's not the one in [`java.util`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html).

Comment: I used sun.misc.Base64Decoder

Comment: Don't use any `sun.*` classes if avoidable. In Java 8, use [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

Comment: [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) uses letters (26 uppercase + 26 lowercase), digit (10), and 2 other characters, usually `+` and `/`, for a total of `26 + 26 + 10 + 2 = 64`. The `*` doesn't belong there. Some decoders will ignore invalid characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table

Comment: Thanks  Andreas, My opinion same as you I test encoding using java.util.Base64 now, Eexcptions occure. Is it just Base64Decoder clsss bug?

Comment: It's not necessarily a bug, just a different approach to the issue.

Comment: If you simply remove the `*`, you get this byte sequence: `89 c5 08 e9 6f d5 89 0e 07 36 70 3a d9 70 db 9c 19 27 0b 80 8e e2 1a 62 cc 4e f6 ea b3 d3 d9 9f 99 fb f5 47 b5 ec b1 d6 dc 4f a5 be 32 b6 a9 e0 7d ec df 56 8f db 4d 5a`

Comment: Thanks Louis, Andreas. It has been a big help